# Python pip install SSLError Windows

Tags: python, pip, installation, anaconda

I've seen this issue addressed before in other posts and it was recommended to used the trusted host prefix when installing a python package.  That has always worked for me but now, for whatever reason, no longer works.  This is the message I get when installing any Python package via Pypi.org. It really doesn't matter what package is involved I get the same error regardless.

I have tried changing the condarc file to turn ssl_verify to false and that does not seem to help and I get the same message. Any ideas?

I'm running the latest version of Python via Anaconda.

Also the curl workaround doesn't appear to work as it simply times out

> (base) C:\Users\name>pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org gpyopt
>   Collecting gpyopt   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
>   redirect=None, status=None))  after connection broken by
>   'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAIL ED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),)': /simple/gpyopt/   Retrying
>   (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
>   after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAIL ED] certificate verify failed
>   (_ssl.c:777)'),)': /simple/gpyopt/   Retrying (Retry(total=2,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))  after
>   connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAIL ED] certificate verify failed
>   (_ssl.c:777)'),)': /simple/gpyopt/   Retrying (Retry(total=1,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))  after
>   connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAIL ED] certificate verify failed
>   (_ssl.c:777)'),)': /simple/gpyopt/   Retrying (Retry(total=0,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))  after
>   connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAIL ED] certificate verify failed
>   (_ssl.c:777)'),)': /simple/gpyopt/   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/gpyopt/: There was a proble m
>   confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org',
>   port=443) : Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/gpyopt/ (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1,  '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),)) -  skipping   Could not find a version
>   that satisfies the requirement gpyopt (from versions:  ) No matching
>   distribution found for gpyopt

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how i get some broken version from **python webiste** when type python windows 27 in google

This one has included python 2 + pip and its working without issue

```
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.msi
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a VPN, this was the same problem for me when I tried to install a package with Vpn connected.

Steps to solve -

1- Disconnect your VPN

2- Try installing the package again